# Regex match for Blocks of repeating digits

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match Blocks of repeating digits such as **27527527** or **45454545** or **49994949**.

I have **8 digits numbers**. I want to create a **regex** that will only match when at least 2 or 3 numbers are repeated in a pattern.

Such as **11046758** is not a valid match. But **11046755** or **110466758** is a valid match.

Currently, I have this regex

```
(\d)\1+
```

The Problem with this regex is it matches **11046758** as well. However, it should only match when at least 2 numbers are repeating themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups with 2 backreferences and a word boundary `\b`

```
\b[0-9]*([0-9])[0-9]*\1[0-9]*([0-9])[0-9]*\2[0-9]*\b
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d*%28%5b0-9%5d%29%5b0-9%5d*%5c1%5b0-9%5d*%28%5b0-9%5d%29%5b0-9%5d*%5c2%5b0-9%5d*%5cb&i=I+am+trying+to+match+Blocks+of+repeating+digits+such+as+27527527+or+45454545+or+49994949.+I+have+8+digits+numbers.+I+want+to+create+a+regex+that+will+only+match+when+at+least+2+or+3+numbers+are+repeated+in+a+pattern.+Such+as+11046758+is+not+a+valid+match.+But+11046755+or+110466758+is+a+valid+match.%0d%0a27527527%0d%0a%0d%0a45454545%0d%0a%0d%0a27527527)

If there should be 8 digits, you can use a positive lookahead. But note that `110466758` will not be valid as that is 9 digits.

```
\b(?=[0-9]{8}\b)[0-9]*([0-9])[0-9]*\1[0-9]*([0-9])[0-9]*\2[0-9]*\b
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3d%5b0-9%5d%7b8%7d%5cb%29%5b0-9%5d*%28%5b0-9%5d%29%5b0-9%5d*%5c1%5b0-9%5d*%28%5b0-9%5d%29%5b0-9%5d*%5c2%5b0-9%5d*%5cb&i=I+am+trying+to+match+Blocks+of+repeating+digits+such+as+27527527+or+45454545+or+49994949.+I+have+8+digits+numbers.+I+want+to+create+a+regex+that+will+only+match+when+at+least+2+or+3+numbers+are+repeated+in+a+pattern.+Such+as+11046758+is+not+a+valid+match.+But+11046755+or+110466758+is+a+valid+match.%0d%0a27527527%0d%0a%0d%0a45454545%0d%0a%0d%0a27527527)

---

If you also want to match `12341234` another option could be to first sort the string, and then find 2 times 2 repeating digits:

```
string[] strings = {
    "11223344",
    "12341234",
    "27527527",
    "11046758"
    };
string pattern = @"\b[0-9]*([0-9])\1[0-9]*([0-9])\2[0-9]*\b";
foreach (String str in strings)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(String.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => c)), pattern);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match {0}", str);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No match for {0}", str);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Match 11223344
Match 12341234
Match 27527527
No match for 11046758
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/6u7RSp)

Comment: But this regex does not match 27527527 or 45454545

Comment: @Waqarulislam It does match `45454545` Do you mean like this? `\b(?=[0-9]{8}\b)[0-9]*([0-9]+)[0-9]*\1[0-9]*([0-9]+)[0-9]*\2[0-9]*\b` https://regex101.com/r/6keqhY/1

Comment: @Waqarulislam I have updated the answer to match 2 repeated single digits that will also match the numbers in the comments.